# Are private swift protocols possible?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

After reading the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) about this I discovered

> In Swift, as in Objective-C, protocol conformance is global—it is not possible for a type to conform to a protocol in two different ways within the same program.

So what is the purpose of the private prefix here

```
private protocol PartyFormViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func partyFormViewController(controller: PartyFormViewController, cancelButtonPressed button: UIBarButtonItem)
}

class PartyFormViewController: GenericViewController {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In Swift `private` means: visible within the current source file.

A private `Type` could conform to a private protocol, look here:

```
private protocol Animal { }
private class Dog: Animal { }

class Zoo {
    private var animals = [Animal]()
    var count : Int { return animals.count }
}
```

Here, Animal and Dog are visible only within the current files. However, they are used by `Zoo` which has internal visibility and exposes the count of the animals to the whole module.

Comment: The only reason I am confused by the notion of a private protocol is that it lies outside of the scope of the class Zoo here. Whereas a private var or private function (declared within 'Zoo') is private to Zoo as indicated by the fact that it is declared within the class. The protocol Animal here is decalred outside of the Scope 'Zoo' and that is what confuses me. I would expect Zoo not to know about it either. Especially considering how that protocol could be declared in some other file.

Comment: @robdashnash: In Swift `private` means visibile within the current source file.

Comment: Please edit your answer with this and I'll accept it.

Comment: This should read `private` (at the file scope) means only accessible,within the current file.  As alluded to, at class scope it means only visible within the class, not file.

Comment: @DavidBerry: No, `private` always means visibile within the file. E.g. this code is perfectly fine `private class Car {
    private func go() {}
}

private class Person {
    private func drive() {
        Car().go()
    }
}`